# how to find coordinates of rectangle, if one cordinate is known of rectangle

Tags: linear-algebra, rectangles

I have one rectangle with four corners say (x1,y1), (x2,y2), (x3,y3),(x4,y4). where (x1,y1) is bottom left corner, (x2,y2) is bottom right , (x3,y3)upper left and (x4,y4) upper right. 
I only have values of (x1,y1)that is (95.946236, 5.907290) and dimension of rectangle is 1.397m length and 0.8128m width or 55 inch X 32 inch. So how i can calculate values of (x2,y2)(x3,y3)&(x4,y4).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the rectangle is not tilted at an angle, the four coordinates should be **`(x1,y1),(x1+l,y1),(x1,y1+w),(x1+l,y1+w)`** where **l=length** and **w=width**.

Comment: Can you please explain it more, i dint get this method..!

Comment: See this image : http://quiz.geeksforgeeks.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/square.png

Comment: In the image example, values of x1, y1, w and l is 10.